# Ansible ad-hoc command with ansible vault

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I want to pass in a password to `ansible`.

The pass is encrypted with ansible vault and I have it in a file and I have the ansible vault pass available for decryption.

I need to use that decrypted password as ansible_password.

So far I have:

> `run.sh`: sh script to run the ad_hoc command I need to run
>
> ```sh
> #!/bin/sh 
> ansible all -i 'somehost,' -m win_ping --extra-vars "ansible_port=5986 \
>  ansible_connection=winrm ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore validate_certs=false \
>  ansible_user=somedomain\s-someserviceaccount ansible_password=___need_decrypted_password___"`
> ```

and

> `someenv_vault.yaml` a file with a vault encrypted pass
>
> ```
> $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
> 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef012345678
> 9abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01
> 23456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789a
> bcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567
> ```

and

> `~/.vault_pass`
>
> ```
> somevaultpassword
> ```

How do I get a decrypted vault password into the ansible ad hoc command?

Comment: Did you try the `--vault-password-file` option?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following

> `run.sh`
>
> ```sh
> #!/bin/bash
> THEPASS=$(ansible-vault decrypt <<JOYPEFF
> \$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
> 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef012345678
> 9abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01
> 23456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789a
> bcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567
> JOYPEFF
> )
> echo "usage ./run.sh <servername(s)> ..."
> echo "e.g. ./run.sh server1,server2"
> ansible all -i "$1," -m win_ping --extra-vars "ansible_winrm_transport=credssp ansible_port=5986 ansible_connection=winrm ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore validate_certs=false ansible_user=somedomain\s-someserviceaccount ansible_password=$THEPASS"
> ```

Comment: Looking at this, you only have the value in the file, not the key.  If the file also contains the key, then you can use the `--vault-password-file` option, and put that file into `group_vars/all/`.

Comment: Can you show me one sample cmd on how to pass '--vault-password-file' in the ansible adhoc cmd.  I tried this cmd, but its erring out. 

 sudo ansible remote_host -m "ping" --vault-password-file cred
[WARNING]: Error in vault password file loading (default): A vault password must be specified to decrypt data
ERROR! A vault password must be specified to decrypt data